# cakePHP - prevent form select list tampering

Tags: php, forms, security, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a simple form with a couple select inputs. One of which is a gender selections.

The input is generated like so:

```
echo $this->Form->input('gender_id', array(
    'options' => array(
        1 => 'Male',
        2 => 'Female'
    )
));
```

How can I ensure that only the given selects can be submit, so that a 3 or something can not be submitted?

I am using the Security component and it seems to protect against field name tampering but not value tampering.

Doing a simple comparison would not be practical for larger select lists like a State select. Also I'm trying to avoid doing extra queries to validate ids.

Comment: There is a recent discussion on this topic here: http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2938-securitycomponent-htmlhelper-check-select-values

Comment: Thanks for the link. Sounds like it's not implemented and will not be added in the future either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require values to be in a specified list for your Model's validation:

```
public $validate = array(
    'gender_id' => array(
      'allowed' => array(
      'rule'    => array('inList', array(1, 2)),
      'message' => 'Please select male or female.'
     )
   )
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make this field in the DB an [ENUM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type) field with allowed value 1 and 2.

You can **not** prevent that somebody will submit a third value, simply by manipulating the DOM or the POST request with FireBug. If it is not a DB value and does not run trough the Model form validation rules you have to do it manually in your controller. Since only there this kind of validation is necessary according to your description.

Comment: I suppose that's doable for a gender field but I don't believe that's as practical for a state field. For that I am using an associated table.

Comment: Then add a foreign key (you should really have these already, Cake is built around them). The DB violation will trigger a cakeError.

Comment: @powtac thanks for the edit. I am not suggesting that a user will not be able to manipulating the DOM. I was more of wondering if Cake cached the select values that could then later be compared to. I am quite surprised that the Security component does not automatically do this for you considering the extent it goes through to valid field names.

Comment: Doesn't it (the sec component) do this? The last time I used it, it added a extra token and when I tried to manipulate the DOM, the sec component prevented it. (But maybe I tried to overcome Model validation)

Comment: It may, and I may be not be implementing it correctly. Unfortunately this part of Cake's book is lacking. see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#form-tampering-prevention